# Connecting Apache Spark 3.0 to Kafka using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, stream-processing

I'm developing a little Big Data project and I was wondering if there is a way to read a stream from a Kafka Topic from Spark Streaming v3.0 using python3.

I've read on the https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/streaming-programming-guide.html that is necessary to link the artifact *spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12* to hande this kind of stream but I've found that those dependencies are incompatible with Python (in the integration guide there are only examples with Java or Scala and from a different version of Spark Streaming, I've read that there isn't a support for the python language: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/streaming-kafka-integration.html)

I've also found this link that could answer my question, but...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960981/does-spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2-10-work-with-python?rq=1

Some more details: actually, I've a stream of json response from https://openweathermap.org/api sent every seconds over a Kafka topic. I want to take this stream to calculate the trends on the actual temperature of a place over the last measurements.

I could switch my current stack choices, so other suggestions are welcome but I won't change Python as my scripting language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by creating a "connector" script in python, using the KafkaConsumer library. It takes data from the stream and publish them on a TCP socker on the localhost. Spark read those data using ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", PORTS).

I've used this guide to setting up the code : https://www.toptal.com/apache/apache-spark-streaming-twitter.

Comment: I have the same problem: I can't able to read frfom a Kafka topic with Spark 3.02...@DavDev can share your solution?

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, you can find the final solution in the project repository: https://github.com/Stojani/LAMA_Climate/tree/master/speed
All the files that you need are inside the /speed directory.